# python code to make excel invisible while running python code and macro

Tags: python, excel, win32com

Below is the python code to make excel workbook invisible. It works but there is a major flaw with the code. The program crashes when I open another saved workbook while this code is running?

```
wb = client.Dispath("Excel.Application")
wb.visible = False
```

Comment: How about we disable user from opening excel file while the program is running, not sure if that is doable because toward the middle, the program also open excel file ?

Comment: Excel has many operations that implicitly use the concept of  a current workbook/worksheet.  Opening a second workbook while it is being driven programmatically is not a good idea, and often leads to crashes.